# Marketing tag not rendering content in Magnolia page

Tags: magnolia

According to [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Marketing+Tags+app), Marketing Tag should render content on the associated page.

Here is what I try to do so far

In unsubscribe-form.yaml

```
title: unsubscribe-form
renderType: freemarker
visible: true
templateScript: /main/templates/pages/unsubscribe-form.ftl
areas:
  header:         # experimental
  headerScripts:
    type: noComponent
```

in unsubscribe-form.ftl

```
...
<head>
[@cms.area name="headerScripts" /]
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

in tag property dialog

[image]
[image]
[image]

When the page is rendered I don't see neither popup window nor meta tag in the header.
In server console I also don't see any exceptions.
What could be wrong?

PS. I also make sure that FTL templates are reloaded in magnolia by removing module's version in config and redeploy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you ruled out the browser cache or any proxies in between you and the server.
Assuming you set up the `headerScripts` area as described in documentation, the most likely reason is that the `modelClass` doesn't exist or is configured incorrectly.

Comment: in first snippet I set `headerScripts`. is this enough? I'm not sure I understood "modelClass doesn't exist or is configured incorrectly".

Comment: Is it what you mean "The module inserts marketing tags into three alternative page areas: bodyBeginScripts, bodyEndScripts and headerScripts.  To function correctly your page templates should contain these areas."  xxxxScripts should contain "modelClass info.magnolia.marketingtags.model.ScriptsAreaModel"?